# Ubuntu Server 15.04

Tags: 14.04

Why is there no Ubuntu server 15.04 listed in the server section of ubuntu's website?  I was considering upgrading my Ubuntu Server 14.04 with xfce and zfs and other software.

Comment: Why would you install a server version for a none-LTS?  That beats the purpose of a server: longevity.

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade to 15.04 from here. http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/
I presume it is not listed under the server section because it is not a LTS version and it has been replaced by 15.10.  The next LTS version to be released will be 16.04 in April.